# Laravel Queue::shouldReceive()

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4, mockery

I have the following in one of my routes

```
$rules = array(
    'name' => 'Required',
    'subject' => 'Required',
    'message' => 'Required',
    'email' => 'Required|Email',
    'recaptcha_response_field' => 'required|recaptcha'
);

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if($validator->fails()){
    return Redirect::to('contact')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
}else{

    $data = array('name' => Input::get('name'),
                  'email' => Input::get('email'),
                  'text' => Input::get('message'),
                  'subject' => Input::get('subject'));  

    Queue::push('ContactQueue', $data);

    return Redirect::to('contact')->with('success', 'Message sent successfully');
}
```

I am trying to write a unit test for the success scenario, I have the following:

```
public function testSuccess(){
    Validator::shouldReceive('make')->once()->andReturn(Mockery::mock(['fails' => false]));

    Queue::shouldReceive('push')->once();

    $this->call('POST', '/contact');

    $this->assertRedirectedTo('/contact');
}
```

But I keep receiving the following error when trying to run phpunit:

`BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager::connected() does not exist on this mock object`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting `Queue::shouldReceive('connected')->once();` 
after `Queue::shouldReceive('push')->once();` 
solved this.

Comment: To further elaborate, even if you use `Queue::shouldReceive('push')->never();` you'll still need the other line somewhere in your code. Perhaps Laravel always initiates the Queue driver even when not needed, so you'll need to mock that.